# SystemVerilog immediate assertion failure at time 0fs

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

I have added an immediate assertion to test that two registers are not programmed to the same value at any given time. I get a failure at time 0fs because all values are uninitialized and are 'x'.

```
always @(*) begin
  assert_reg_val_cmp:
  assert (reg != 1'b1) else $error("...error msg...");
end
```

Is there a way to cleanly disable this assertion only at initial time? I could use `reg !== 1'b1` comparison, which compares 'x' too, but I want to catch any 'x' states after 0fs.

Comment: Do you have a reset signal that you can check before checking the assertion?

Comment: I can, but I am not sure how the syntax will work. I know the syntax for concurrent assertions, but where would `disable iff (reset !== 1'b1)` go?

Comment: `disable iff` doesn't work an immediate assertion. You can use: `assert (reset === 1'b1 || reg != 1'b1) else $error("...error msg...");` or `if (reset == 1'b1) assert (reg != 1'b1) else $error("...error msg...");`

Comment: Thank you. I had inverted the polarity on reset and that is why it did not work. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using SystemVerilog,please use `always_comb` instead of `always @(*)`**. The latter has a problem in that it does not execute if one of the inputs turns out to be a constant.

If you want to make sure a register is initialized at time 0, then used a deferred assertion.

```
always_comb begin
  assert_reg_val_cmp:
  assert #0 (reg != 1'b1) else $error("...error msg...");
end
```

But why do you not want to use a concurrent assertion for this?